# ViewBag returns empty in PartialView but shows the value in debugger

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-partialview, viewbag

I'm trying to return a value from my controller to a `PartiaView` through `ViewBag`, but it doesn't show the value at all.

Here is my controller:

```
public PartialViewResult Index(int articleid)
{
    var allcomments = _db.SelectAll();
    var comments = from c in allcomments
        where c.ArticleID == articleid
        select c;

    var result = comments.ToList();

    ViewBag.CommentCount = result.Count;

    return PartialView(result);
}
```

I run the action method in another view using `Html.RenderPartial()`:

```
@using ClearBlog.Helpers
@model ClearBlog.Models.ViewModels.SingleArticleViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

// stuff here

@{ Html.RenderAction("Index", "Comments", new { articleid = 6002 }); }
```

and finally here is the partial view:

```
@using AutoMapper.Internal
@model IEnumerable<ClearBlog.Models.Comment>

@ViewBag.CommentCount Comment(s):

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    // some stuff
}
```

In partial view it renders nothing but if I set a breakpoint in partial view then in debugger in locals tab it shows the correct value:

[image]

Comment: If you cast @ViewBag.CommentCount to an int in Razor code, what happens?

Comment: Where did you put your breakpoint exactly?

Comment: @ataravati line 4 at partial view

Comment: By the way, why do you even need the ViewBag? You're passing `result` as Model to your partial view. You can just do `@result.Count` in your partial view.

Comment: By line 4 you mean `foreach`?

Comment: @ataravati, You're right in this case, but why is it not working in my case??

Comment: @ataravati line 4 means `@ViewBag.CommentCount`

Comment: Replace it with `@ViewBag.CommentCount.ToString()` or `@Html.Raw(ViewBag.CommentCount)`.

Comment: @ataravati It worked but it's very annoying because intellisense doesn't help with that.

Comment: ViewBag is a dynamic object. Of course, intellisense doesn't work, because it doesn't know anything about the datatype. And, for that same reason, you'll have to explicitly convert it to string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In line 4 of the partial view file `@ViewBag.CommentCount` should be `@ViewBag.CommentCount.ToString()`. It's also possible to do the convert in controller just before assigning the value to `ViewBag` so that we don't have to do it in view.